# Regex to differentiate APIs

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex to help determine the number the number of times an API is called. We have multiple APIs and this API is of the following format:

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}`

The above endpoint also supports query parameters so the following requests would be valid:

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}?start=0&limit=10`

The following requests are also valid:

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}/`

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}`

We also have the following endpoints:

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/type/`

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/name/`

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}/price`

My current regex to extract calls made only to /foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id} looks something like this:

`\/foo\/bar\/(.+)\/id\/(?!type|name)(.+)`

But the above regex also includes calls made to `/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}/price` endpoint.

I can check if the string after {id}/ isn't price and exclude calls made to price but it isn't a long term solution since if we add another endpoint we may need to update the regex.

Is there a way to filter calls made only to:

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}`

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}/`

`/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}?start=0&limit=10`

Such that `/foo/bar/{barId}/id/{id}/price` isn't also pulled in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\/foo\/bar\/(.+)\/id\/(?!type|name)(.+)
```

There is something in your RegEx which is the cause to your problem. `"(.+)"` RegEx code matches every character after it. So replace it with `"[^/]"` and add the following code `"/?(?!.+)"`. This is working for me.

```
/foo/bar/([^/]+)/id/(?!type|name)([^/]+)/?(?!.+)
```